# Файл скачивается с битой кодировкой Yii

Tags: yii, fileupload, download

Использую такую функцию для скачивания файла -

```
   $file =  'user_file/мой_файл.txt';
Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile('Мой_файл.txt', file_get_contents($file));
```

Либо вобще не срабатывает скачивание, либо с битой кодировкой

Answer (score 1):

Задавайте на сервере кодировку

```
header('Charset=UTF-8');
```

Так же обратите внимание на кодировку в вашей IDE  или текстовом редакторе. 
Посмотрите, в какой кодировке файл лежит на сервере. Логично, что отдавать его нужно в такой же.

Comment: Что-то тут не так, http-заголовки пишутся в формате `Название: значение`, а такого особого случая я в документации не обнаружил

Comment: Оно будет работать и так, полный вариант - header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  Content-Type мы опустили. Хотя, могу ошибаться, конечно.